# Proving that E[L] ≤ E[L|L>n], where where the inequality is strict if P(L≤ n)> 0

Tags: probability, probability-theory, inequality

How do I show that E[L] ≤ E[L|L>n] for any discrete random variable L, where the inequality is strict if P(L≤ n)> 0. E[X] represents the expected value of the random variable X.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Could you please let us know what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Use the facts that $ELI_{L>n} \geq nP\{L>n\} \, \,$ (1) and

$ELI_{L\leq n}\leq n P\{L\leq n\} \,\, $ (2).

We get $ELI_{L\leq n} P\{X>n\}\leq n P\{X>n\}P\{L\leq n\} \leq ELI_{L>n} P\{L\leq n\}$.

This gives  $ELI_{L\leq n} P\{X>n\} \leq ELI_{L>n} (1-P\{L> n\})$. Simple algebraic manipulation now gives the desired inequality. If $P\{L\leq n\} >0$ then the inequality in (1) is strict and you get strict inequality.

Comment: Hello, thank you for answering the question. I did not understand how you concluded (1) and (2). Are you using Markov's inequality and assuming L is positive?

Comment: If $f\leq g$ then $\int f \leq \int g$. For (1) integrate both sides of $nI_{\{L>n\}} \leq LI_{\{L>n\}}$. Similar argument for (2).